# Stuck in nether in creative mode on xbox one and can't find portal to get back

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am on Minecraft in creative mode on xbox one and am lost in nether. I have tried for hours to find my portal and can't. All the responses I see tell you how to get out if you are on a computer and not in xbox one. Anybody have a way to help me get out?

Comment: If youre in creative... whats stopping you from making a new portal...?

Comment: Don't have the materials. Also someone told me if you do that it will delete your world that you created and you will lose everything. Not sure if that's true.

Comment: ... but youre in creative mode... you literally have infinite of every material in the game... unless creative is different on the console version v.s. the PC version. Which I dont see why it would be...

Answer (score 0):

You could just die? or make another portal if you want. You might want to look into this a bit more before asking us because I feel this has a lot of answers already.

Comment: You can't just die on xbox in creative mode. I spent hours looking through this with no help. If you don't have the material to create another portal what can you do? All the answers are for computer version and not xbox or for survival mode.

Comment: I am unsure of xbox version, but in Java Edition you could dig straight down beyond bedrock to the void to die in creative.  How do you not have the materials to create another portal in creative?